# How can I fill old screw holes in wood on the exterior of a house?

Tags: wood, exterior

The exterior of my house is stucco, but there are some spots that have vertical wood planks. I think this was considered "in style" when my house was built (1950s).

Anyway, over the years previous owners had installed various things to these wood panels - I imagine an exterior security light, for instance - that now have empty screw holes. I'd like to fill these, as they're a tad unsightly and, I imagine, are just asking for fungus/mold growth.

Pardon my ignorance, but how do I go about filling these? Is there a product designed specifically to fill holes in exterior wood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fill the holes with Wood Fillter which is available at almost all home stores:

[image: Wood Filler]

You fill the hole with it, and let it dry. Once dry, sand it flush with the other surface, prime and paint.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I figured there was some product designed to do just this.